# providedin 'root' angular service is undefined

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

The providedIn property of the Injectable is not working. I have set the provided in property to root but it is undefined when accessed by components through the constructor like so

```
    public constructor(
    private readonly testService: TestService,
) {}
```

In the case above, angular throws an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TestService')`.

In the docs the link on providing a service https://angular.io/guide/providers states, after setting `providedIn: 'root"` that

> You can now inject UserService anywhere in your application.

This implies you don't need to do anything else to get access to the service. But in my case I get undefined.

This might somehow be connected to the location of the service in the file hierarchy, as depending on which index.ts file is importing it it will actually be available. But that seems like a bug, since it shouldn't matter where the service is located - it should always be injected in root.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Assuming your `TestService` indeed does have a `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` annotation, there is nothing wrong with your code. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)?

Comment: has you import the service in your component? `import {TestService} from './../test.service.ts'` (well the direction and the name of the file.ts can change)

Comment: @eliseo Yes I have imported it, sadly enough.

Comment: can you share your app structure with relevance to this service?

Comment: @Eliseo I did import the serivce... but I did so through the index.ts which apparently can break the import in certain circumstances. I added an answer about this.

Answer (score 3):

This error ended up being a red herring for me. The reason the service was undefined all the time was not due to the providedIn field, but rather because I was importing index.ts instead of importing the TestService directly.

For anyone stuck on this issue, make sure you are importing the service directly, even if it is provided in root, because of circular dependency shenanigans, some components can attempt to access your root service too quickly through the index.ts and it just fails.